# How do I add icons / images to my CV

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I wish to add the icons for my Microsoft certifications to my CV, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will be supporting full Markdown in all free text fields in the next version, to be released by Oct. 28th.

Comment: Does that mean with intraword support?

Answer (score 2):

And there are people that want to add Waffle-sharks with freaking lasers in their heads. That's the reason that now we can't put images in the CV.

*May be* Jeff & co. might reconsider and trust we'll behave, but **I** wouldn't trust us to behave.

Comment: Wouldn't the lasers be better weapons **on** their heads?

Comment: @random: no, this way whenever they shoot everyone in the room will just *have* to freeze in disgust as the sharks heads open outwards. Not that that would work with people here in MSO, but for them we still have the laser.

Comment: So then you have shark head soup and you can use their fins for spoons.